# Tomcat web app needs to work with SSL Client authentication?

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

I've run up against something an issue I've not been able to solve.

I am running a java web app in tomcat. I need this app to make a get request out to a 3rd party web service (should be simple enough I do this with loads of other services).

However this 3rd party service uses an .pk12 SSL certificate to authenticate me as a client. I have been provided a .pk12 certificate file and a password. This works if I use them on a windows machine.

I've done reading on similar issues and the guides seam to be about how to setup the tomcat with SSL auth as the server. Not acting as the client to present the SSL cert when requested by the server.

Any help / advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just on a side note I have tried importing the .pk12 into the java truststore and I have confirmed the user certificate is there. I've restarted tomcat and tested this did not work still get a 401 error because tomcat is not presenting the SSL client certificate to authenticate with.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Connector
       protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
       port="8443" maxThreads="200"
       scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
       SSLCertificateFile="/usr/local/ssl/server.crt"
       SSLCertificateKeyFile="/usr/local/ssl/server.pem"
       SSLVerifyClient="optional" SSLProtocol="TLSv1+TLSv1.1+TLSv1.2"/>
```

for more informations 
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html

Comment: Isn't this just basically setting up tomcat to be available on SSL? if so I already have that. All my services are SSL only we dont do HTTP.

Comment: your url will be https:localhost:8443/appsname

Comment: whats your tomcat config ? and whats the browser response ?

Comment: my app is already available via SSL that is not what I am trying to achieve, Without going to business specific details. Basically the app on our side will take customer details and then will make several call's out to 3rd party data providers. Those providers will respond back with an XML response which we then parse and update our records accordingly. Normally all other providers use API keys etc. This new provider needs us to present an SSL certificate our user. This is not the SSL certificate for our server. [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19424-01/820-4811/aakhe/index.html)